# How do I prove that for every monic polynomial $P$ there exists a linear operator $f$ such that $P$ is the minimal polynomial of $f$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials, companion-matrices

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and
> $P(T)=T^{k}+a_{k-1}T^{k-1}+\dots+a_{1}T+a_{0}\in\mathbb{F}[T]$ a monic
> polynomial.
>
> **Prove:** There exist a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$, a linear operator $f:V\to V$ and a vector $v\in V $ such that the minimal
> polynomial is equal to $P$
>
> $(min_{v}^{f}=P)$
>
> *Hint:* use the Companion matrix of P

I'd appreciate some help, I've been stuck on this problem for a good while. Moreover, I can't quite figure out how to use the companion matrix in my proof.

Comment: You should edit your question to show us what you have tried. This will help you get more helpful answers and avoid downvotes.

Comment: @C-RAM problem is that I don't really know how to even approach this question, so I'm looking for a little bit of guidance on how to get started

Comment: Fair enough; I can sympathise. Can you at least provide context for where this problem is from, and what you understand about it (your backround). Providing something more than just the problem statement is necessary according to site guidelines; it may help you get better answers, and should prevent more downvotes (to be clear, this one wasn't me).

Comment: @C-RAM Sure, I'm a computer science undergraduate, this question is from a weekly assignment in the Linear Algebra II course. I'll try to provide more context next time, sorry.

Comment: What's your understanding of the relationship between matrices and linear operators?

Comment: @blargoner I know that every linear transformation can be represented by a matrix, and since a linear operator is a linear transformation, it means that every linear operator can be represented by a matrix. I'm pretty sure the opposite is true as well - every matrix (including the companion matrix of P) is a linear transformation, although I think it doesn't necessarily mean it's a linear operator, just a linear transformation.

Comment: How do operator and transformation differ in your book, and would that matter for this problem? Would the linear operator corresponding to the companion matrix work?